# XAML - Image scale -only down when needed

Tags: xaml

I have a xml file containing 1 small graphic and 1 big graphic.

In my XAML i have a column that contains both graphics.
But the problem is that the first grahic is smaller then the column, so it was scaling the image up, to fit the column... dont know why!
Anyway, I was setting the attribute Strech="None" to the < Image> element, and it worked out great, accept that the bigger graphic now is to big for the column, so it cuts the graphic in half!

What can I do?

I tried Strech="None" together with MaxWidth="8cm", not helping the bigger graphic to be scaled down.

Summary: I want that graphics never should be scaling up, only down when needed.

Please help me!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in ViewBox's and set your Height/Widths to it instead.

Comment: Is there some alternative attribute saying keep original size of graphic, but keep inside the parent grid or paragraph?! Thanks

Comment: A viewbox will scale an image while retaining its resolution in most cases. Did you set hard values on the Viewbox (using pixel size, not cm) like Height="150"?